# AWS 400 Bad Request error C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, httpwebrequest

I am tasked with developing an application that Posts data to the client's Amazon Web Service api. The instructions from client were that I have to use the POST method for URL http://ec.*******.compute.amazonaws.com/api and gave me a token to use for authentication.

My C# code looks like this

```
SystemSettings _Settings = GetSystemSettings(); //URL and Token values
try
{
    JObject jsonObject = GetJsonData();
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(_Settings.HttpService);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Settings.BearerToken))
    {
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + _Settings.BearerToken);
     }
     //Uploading JSON
     request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
     //using Http POST Method
     request.Method = "POST";
     //Start uploading data
     StreamWriter httpStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
     httpStream.Write(jsonObject.ToString());
     httpStream.Close(); // Close stream
     httpStream.Dispose(); //Dispose stream

     //Check for response from the web server
     WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); //Error comes here
     .
     .
     .
     .
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error("ERROR Uploading to stream(" + _Settings.HttpService + ")", ex);
}
```

The request ends up with a 400 Bad Request. Does this require working with Amazon SDK to connect to use the Bearer Token?

The customer has said the following:

> Our API Authentication is RFC6750, Can you please make a request to
>   the API as follows:

```
POST /api/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ec.************.compute.amazonaws.com
Authorization: Bearer ***TOKEN***
```

Comment: Are you interfacing to Amazon API Gateway, or to your customer's own API endpoint? Sounds like the latter. If that's the case then AWS is probably nothing to do with this and their SDKs won't help you - you'll need to understand the customer's own custom interface (I would ask them directly).

Comment: It's the later (customer's own API endpoint). They told me the authentication is according to RFC 6750. I have edited the question to include the customer's response

Comment: Just checking: EC2 public DNS names by default are similar to ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com. You indicated ec.************.compute.amazonaws.com. You are talking to the correct API endpoint, yes? Are they receiving your POSTs? I would consider taking C# etc. out of the picture and test using Postman, curl, or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod so I checked using Postman and it came back with the following:
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_request" Status →400 Bad Request  and the body said {"Status": "Invalid Parameter" } does this mean there is no error on my side?

Comment: RFC 6750 indicates that response means "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter or parameter value, repeats the same parameter, uses more than one method for including an access token, or is otherwise malformed." So I suspect an error on your side. Is the bearer token correct? Is there any debugging or logs available from their API side?